# How to find list of active Queries used/Queried on Cassandra Database?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

Is it possible to find list of all queries that application uses to query Cassandra Database?

Do we have any option in Cassandra Database to pull all the queries queried, instead of gathering from the application? From Performance Service section of Options, one can track slow queries but how do we see all the queries?

Can reducing the threshold to 0 in cql_slow_log_options, hits the slow_log query to display all the queries in Opscenter?
dse.yaml
cql_slow_log_options:
    enabled: true
    threshold: 0.0

```
Versions
DSE 4.8
OpsCenter 5.4
```

Thanks